# Angular Components CSS

Tags: css, angular

we have an Angular component inside of a normal Website, and their CSS styles mess with our Angular component styles. Is there a way to prevent this? Maybe include some Angular package or something similar?

Comment: Please provide examples.

Comment: If you need custom CSS for only one component, you may use Component style. [The styles specified in @Component metadata apply only within the template of that component.](https://angular.io/guide/component-styles)

Comment: sorry for the unclear problem. we have styles defined in our angular application. but when we deploy the "whole package", the angular application has misplaced styles, because the css of the wrapper website messes with them. what i need is to tell angular to ignore ALL styles that are not coming from withing the angular app itself.

Comment: You can try to set viewencapsulation to shadowDom on the app.component.